# how to echo php file without pars?

Tags: php

how to read a `php` file and echo it in a `html` file?
i try to use `readfile()` , `file()` `file_get_content()` to read a `php` file.
but when i echo `file_string` its parsed and then show.
how i can prevent to pars `stirng` var that included `php` codes.

here my code:

```
<?php
$path = '..../ex.php';
$source = fopen($path , "r");
echo fread($source,filesize($path ));
fclose($source);
?>
```

how to echo $source without compiled or parsed.

Comment: there is no `file_string` in your code. also, php tags are not parsed when echoed this way. maybe your `$path` is an URL? then it's parsed by its server, before even read by your code, and you can't prevent that from happening.

Comment: i try to set this => E:\kar\php-directory-listing-and-editor\mdr.php5  
but parsed.
here is my project : https://github.com/m-gh/php-directory-listing-and-editor/

Comment: [highlight_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) perhaps?

Comment: as you state htmlspecialchars based answers would work, i strongly suspect there isn't any PHP parsed, but you use some browser that incorrectly tries to render `<?` as a tag. you might want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: @MarkBaker . oh its very good answer . i exactly search for your function . you are really engineer. thanks :)

Comment: @nonchip this is not browser incorrect.
my code write in a php file then server send file to php compiler and php compiler compile every thing Apart from quote (') and string in textarea html tag and another things that i don't know those

Comment: @masoud.gh wrong. php never parses anything you pass to `echo`. is `$path` a path or a URL? in the latter case, the server you're fetching it from will parse it beforehand and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this function

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```

php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

`fread` should works fine. Remember that when you use `echo` it prints `<?php` opening tag and in rendered page it can be not visible.

To test it, just try with `var_dump`:

```
$content = fread($source,filesize($path));
var_dump($content);
```

Comment: i try this.its same as echo with a little change.still parsed.
i want to exactly put text ex.php file in html and cant do.

Comment: @unknown btw, did you try `<pre>`? this doesn't seem to be a PHP or server side problem...

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that the code is not showing up completely in your HTML page, because the browser is trying to interpret `<?php` as HTML tags. The solution is to **HTML encode** any text which may contain characters with a special meaning in HTML:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('..../ex.php'));
```

See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: if this works, then the question was wrong :P (see the part about php actually being parsed)

Comment: @nonchip The question is *terrible*, I'm just trying a lucky guess at parsing the question itself.

Comment: Well I guess English isn't the OP's first language. But I thought it was clear he was asking how to prevent it being parsed. ("how i can prevent to pars stirng var that included php codes.")

Comment: @Nick "Pars" needs to be defined. It probably doesn't relate to the PHP parser and interpreter at all. Hence we can *guess* what the question is really about, but it's hardly clear.

Comment: @deceze Well, the question also included the line, "how to echo $source without compiled or parsed." The English is poor but a hell of a lot better than anything I could write in any language other than English. Give the guy a break!

Comment: @NickRice the problem is, that there is neither a compilation nor a parsing going on, but some browser bug mishandling the `<? … ?>` sequence. so not the language is the main problem with the question, but the conclusion php would be parsed (which leads me to the assumption the OP didn't use any HTML-source-viewer-feature, which, in combination with incorrect DOM handling, leads me to the conclusion they're using IE, which is pretty bad for development btw)

Comment: @nonchip I believe virtually all browsers will try to **parse** `<...` as HTML tags, not just IE.

Comment: @deceze but at least chrome and firefox would see that it's no valid HTML and just ignore it, while konqueror afaik would render it as plain text. so the statement "it's parsed and then shown" is wrong, as it suggests there being any output from that "parsing".

Comment: @NickRice I didn't say anything about the OP, I just said the question, as a question, is terrible. Yes, a language barrier probably has something to do with that, but that doesn't make the question any better.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$path = 'ex.php';
$source = fopen($path , "r");
echo "<textarea style='border:0px; overflow: hidden; width:100%; height:100% '>";
echo fread($source,filesize($path ));
echo "</textarea>";
fclose($source);
```

Comment: so @masoud.gh you actually lied in the comment above: it was your browser, not php.

Comment: @nonchip yes. you are right. thanks. i must delete or chabge question.
please send an edit if you have a time.thanks again